# How can I make part of a Perl regular expression negative optional?

Tags: perl

I want match

```
my @array = ( 'Tree' , 'JoeTree','Joe');

    foreach (@array ) {
      if ( $_ =~ /^(Joe)[^Tree]/gi) {
        print "matched $_";
      }
    }
```

It matching only Joe.  it should not matching anything else

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you do and do not want your regexp to match.  What you're trying to accomplish is not clear.

Comment: Tree, you've been asking a lot of poorly-phrased questions lately, and it is difficult to help you: please read [Jon Skeet's guide to Writing the Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match only 'Joe' as the whole text?

```
/^(Joe)$/
```

or match 'Joe' as the word alone?

```
/\b(Joe)\b/
```

or match 'Joe' not followed by 'Tree'?

```
/^(Joe)(?!Tree)/
```

Comment: after that i have some strings

Answer (score 6):

You dont need regular expressions for this:

```
if ($_ eq 'Joe') {
    print "matched $_";
}
```